# How to split ASCII file by integers/digits?

Tags: r, excel, ascii, spss

If I have an ASCII text file that reads like this:

```
12345
```

and I want to separate it by integers so that it becomes

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  2  3  4  5
```

In other words, each integer is a variable.
I know I can use the `read.fwf` in R but since I have nearly 500 variables in my dataset, is there a better way to divide the integers up into their own columns than having to put `widths=c(1,)` and repeat the "1," 500 times?

I also tried importing the ASCII file into Excel and SPSS but both don't allow me to put in the variable breaks at fixed integer distances.

Comment: `data.frame(t(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]]))` where `x <- 12345`

Comment: With `read.fwf()` you do not need to explicitly repeat the `1` 500 times, you can have `widths=rep(1, 500)`.

Comment: @RonakShah, your suggestion will not work because the question says the file will contain lines of up to 500 digits (though, I admit this was not clearly explained and had to be deduced from the issue with setting `widths` in `read.fwf()`), so 500 digits cannot be read into your numeric variate `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the width of the file by reading in one row as-is, then use that for read_fwf. Using tidyverse functions,

```r
library(readr)
library(stringr)

path <- "path_to_data.txt" # your path

# one pass of the data
pass <- read_csv(path, col_names = FALSE, n_max = 1) # one row, no header
filewidth <- str_length(pass[1, ]) # width of first row

# use fwf with specified number of columns
df <- read_fwf(path, fwf_widths(rep(1, filewidth)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `read.fwf()`, which was your initial choice.

```
# for the example only, a two line source with different line lengths
input <-  textConnection("12345\n6789")

df1 <- read.fwf(input, widths = rep(1, 500))

ncol(df1)
# [1] 500
```

But assume you actually have less than 500 (as you say, and is the case in this example), then the extra columns with all values set to NA can be removed as follows. This uses your longest line to determine the number of columns that are retained.

```
df1 <- df1[, apply(!is.na(df1), 2, all)]

df1
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
# 2  6  7  8  9  NA
```

However, if no missing values are acceptable, then use `any()` to use your shortest line to determine the number of columns that are retained.

```
df1 <- df1[, apply(!is.na(df1), 2, any)]

df1
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  6  7  8  9
```

Of course, if you know the exact line length and all lines are the same length, then just set `widths = rep(1, x)` with `x` set to the known length.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2010 or later, you can import the file using `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`). When you edit the input, there is an option to `split columns` and specify the number of characters:

[image]

This tool is included in Excel 2016, and is a free Microsoft add-in for Excel 2010 and later.